# Flash error - Security Sandbox Violation - on integrating Gigya in Flash

Tags: flash, security, sandbox, frame-rate, gigya

I am working on a existing Flash project (a Flash based game), where I need to integrate social login widget Gigya. I researched and finalized using Adobe Flash Platform Services Social.

The problem is, I successfully integrated that in a test Flash file that I initially prepared. But when I integrate it in the source file of my actual Flash project, I get following error:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***

SecurityDomain 'http://cdn.gigya.com/wildfire/WFApi.ashx?f=gs&asver=as3&service=socialize&enabledProviders=facebook%2Ctwitter%2Cyahoo%2Cmessenger%2Cgoogle%2Clinkedin%2Cmyspace%2Caol%2Corkut%2Cwordpress&services=socialize&APIKey=[---myApiKey---]' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///D|/FlashProjects/game.swf'

SecurityError: Error #2070: Security sandbox violation: caller http://cdn.gigya.com/wildfire/WFApi.ashx?f=gs&asver=as3&service=socialize&enabledProviders=facebook%2Ctwitter%2Cyahoo%2Cmessenger%2Cgoogle%2Clinkedin%2Cmyspace%2Caol%2Corkut%2Cwordpress&services=socialize&APIKey=[---myApiKey---] cannot access Stage owned by file:///D|/FlashProjects/game.swf.

at flash.display::Stage/requireOwnerPermissions()
at flash.display::Stage/addEventListener()
at com.Gigya.Lib::FixFocusManagerBugs/addFocusInAndOutHandlers()
at com.Gigya.Lib::FixFocusManagerBugs/onUiTopElementAddedToStage()
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
at com.Gigya.Apps.Socialize.Common::BaseForm()
at com.Gigya.Apps.Socialize.Login.Forms::MiniLogin()
at com.Gigya.Apps.Socialize.Login::LoginApp/showLoginUI()
at com.Gigya.Lib::ExternalClassLoader/onSwfLoaded()
at com.Gigya.Lib::ExternalClassLoader/ecl_INIT()
```

Please note that I have also included 
Security.allowDomain("cdn.gigya.com"); 
in my code, but it works in my initial test Flash (a minimal file with 2 frames and no extra components), but does not seem to be working for my actual game Flash.

Has anyone faced such an error?

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated each frame and the related actionscript code in my flash file one by one, saw that including one frame on the way caused this problem, I removed it, ran the flash file and everything worked perfect.

Still not sure how the problem was occurring, but it does not occur anymore now :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're loading a SWF, and that SWF needs to access the loader's (game's) stage? In that case, try to specify that they are in the same application and security domains when you load it:

```
var loader : Loader;
var context : LoaderContext;

context = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain,
                                    SecurityDomain.currentDomain);    

loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaderComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url), context);
```

This should load the SWF into the same application domain as the caller, which should allow them both to access each other.